# How can I delete a file when File.delete() refuses to work?

Tags: java, file-io, windows-10, netbeans-8

I realize that there are a number of threads covering this topic, but everything I have found so far failed to get the job done, so I'm thinking I must be missing something.

I have a section of code which is supposed to allow the user to select a name from a list. These names have been loaded from an encrypted file called users.ldf (an encrypted file format used only by my software). Once the user has chosen a name, they press a button which fires off this section of code. The code *should* go through the file, copy every line to a new file except for the one which was selected, delete the old file and then rename the new file as the same name as the old file which was deleted, thereby removing the name from the list. However, the old file is never deleted and the new file is never renamed. Here is the code:

```
private void delUserBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    String user = lm.getElementAt(userList.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
        try {
            Encryption e = new Encryption();
            File oldfile = new File("libs/users.ldf");
            File newfile = new File("libs/temp.ldf");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newfile, false));
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(oldfile);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
                String line = e.decrypt(lineFromFile);

                if (!line.contains(user)) {
                    writer.write(e.encrypt(line));
                    System.out.println("Keeping user " + line);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Erasing user " + line);
                }

            }

            try {

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                scanner.close();
                System.gc();

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }

            oldfile.delete();
            newfile.renameTo(new File("libs/users.ldf"));
            lm.clear();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User " + user + " removed!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EditUsers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EditUsers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

I have tried:

Setting oldfile.setWritable(true) before deleting.
Using BufferedWriter instead of PrintWriter and also FileOutputStream.
Running the garbage collector.
All other instances of the file anywhere in the program are closed and flushed.
I have tried putting the flush and close parts in a `finally` block, but even if I write...

```
finally {
    try {
    //Flush, close, System.gc etc....
    } catch (IOException exc) {
}
```

NetBeans highlights an error and says `finally without try`.

None of these worked. No exception is thrown, even if a try/catch is added, and the code executes as if it had worked properly, but the files remain untouched.

I should mention, I also ran the code with:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("del", oldfile");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

which resulted in the exception "Could not find the specified file". I checked and double checked the file path, and the file had been ready perfectly well so the location was as expected.
For information, the class Encryption simply receives a string, encrypts it and returns the encrypted string, so has no instance of the file contained within it.

Is there any other methodology I can use to erase this file?

I am running Win10, NetBeans 8.0.2 and the most recent version of the JDK.
Many thanks,

G

Comment: First: use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Second: use[`java.nio` instead of the outdated `File` api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html).

Comment: What exception do you get when you run it? What is the reason it doesn't work?

I suspect a permissions issue.

Comment: No exceptions are thrown, `oldfile` simply is not deleted and `newfile` is not renamed. The code executes as if it had worked perfectly. I should add this to the question.

Comment: Getting same issue with java.nio also :/

Comment: You get no response and no exception (I hope you're not ignoring them)?

Comment: Btw, what does `oldfile.getCanonicalPath()` give you? Do you really check the correct file?

Comment: Yes, this is how I checked the file path, and it was an identical result to showing the file in the Windows file explorer address bar :/

Comment: So if you remove that file using the Windows Explorer, then the program doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Indeed. If I manually delete `users.ldf` there is a `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the best I can come up with is a bit of an ugly fix, and is far from perfect.

I'm now also writing a batch file which deletes and renames the relevant files, and and executing that with a `ProcessBuilder`. It works except for when there are file privilege problems.